# How can I click on a pin in a Google map embedded from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

There is a map embedded in a webpage. I want to click on a pin in the map. I can inject JS onto a page, or use any API that is available to Selenium.

The problem is that I can't find the pin in the embedded map on the page.

Possible solutions:
I've thought about getting ahead of it and diverting registration for the click listener, but I would appreciate it if someone has done this before and can offer me a tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was for a test case with Nightwatch.js where I needed to click on a pin in the map(location).  Since I can control test cases and only have one location, I could just assume the view was centered on the pin.  So:

```
browser.execute(function() {
function clickPin(){
 var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('map-canvas')[0];
 var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
 var centerY = (rect.bottom - rect.top);
 var centerX = (rect.right - rect.left);
 var divX = document.createElement("div");
 divX.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 divX.id = 'offsetX';
 divX.innerHTML = centerX.toString();
 var divY = document.createElement("div");
 divY.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 divY.innerHTML = centerY.toString();
 divY.id = 'offsetY';
 document.head.appendChild(divX);
 document.head.appendChild(divY);
}
clickPin();
}, [], function(result){});
browser.pause(3000);
browser.waitForElementPresent(`//*[@id="offsetX"]`, 3000);
var relX = browser.getValue(`//*[@id="offsetX"]`);
var relY = browser.getValue(`//*[@id="offsetY"]`);
//set cursor position to center and click (fragile)
browser.moveToElement(`//*[@class="map-canvas"]`, relX, relY).mouseButtonClick();
```